# inserting datetime into database

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, datetime, sql-insert

Can anyone explain how to insert datetime into SQLite database using python?
which datatype should be datetime, I tried many different ways

my doubt is based on the problem set 7 in cs50, we use flask as a web framework

`history` is the name of the database
`transaction` is name of field

```
db.execute("INSERT INTO history (transaction) VALUES(:d)",
             d=datetime.datetime.today())
```

error message, I receive this message when I run the application

```
builtins.RuntimeError
RuntimeError: near "transaction": syntax error [SQL: "INSERT INTO history (transaction) VALUES('2019-05-19 17:14:25')"] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`transaction` is a [reserved word](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html) in SQLite.

```
sqlite> INSERT INTO history (transaction) VALUES('2019-05-19 17:14:25');
Error: near "transaction": syntax error
```

In order to disambiguate reserved words they have to be specially quoted. In this case as an identifier with double quotes.

```
sqlite> INSERT INTO history ("transaction") VALUES('2019-05-19 17:14:25');
```

Rather than constantly having to remember to quote `transaction`, I'd recommend renaming the column; `created_at` is very common for a row timestamp. I'd also recommend [using an ORM rather than writing SQL by hand](https://www.fullstackpython.com/object-relational-mappers-orms.html); it will handle all the quoting for you, and has a great many other benefits.

Comment: I tried what you said it showing no error but when I see the database  the value of created_at is 'NULL', can you please tell why it is happening